# Get element whose id is data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, element

I have a container whose id is part of the response of an ajax call. I create those containers dynamically.
I need to get that element in a function. My code is:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'message';
div.id=data[i].name;

var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "Ha realizado check-in en " + data[i].name;
div.appendChild(p);

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '#';
a.className = 'bt-enter';
a.innerHTML = 'Cerrar';
a.addEventListener('click', function () {
     jQuery("#data[i].name").fadeOut();   //This line is the one I have to change
});
div.appendChild(a);
document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0].appendChild(div)
}
```

Comment: `jQuery("#" + data[i].name).fadeOut();` Where did you appended the element `a`?

Comment: is the code in a loop, if so share that too

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a closure in a loop, you can't access those vaiables directly.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'message';
    div.id = data[i].name;

    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = "Ha realizado check-in en " + data[i].name;
    div.appendChild(p);

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = '#' + data[i].name;
    a.className = 'bt-enter';
    a.innerHTML = 'Cerrar';
    a.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this.href).fadeOut(); //This line is the one I have to change
    });
    div.appendChild(a);
    document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0].appendChild(div)
}
```

Note: Since you are using jQuery, use it for object creation also like

```
var $section = $('section').eq(0);
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    var $div = $('<div />', {
        'class': 'message',
        id: item.name
    }).appendTo($section);
    $('<p />', {
        html: "Ha realizado check-in en " + item.name
    }).appendTo($div);
    var $a = $('<a />', {
        href: '#',
            'class': 'bt-enter',
        html: 'Cerrar'
    }).appendTo($div);
    $a.click(function () {
        $div.fadeOut();
    });
});
```